# Correct way to initialise a class Object() in Python with *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying my hand at a little class initialisation, with `*args` and `**kwargs`, in Python, and I am coming up with a `object has no attribute named x` error.

```
class APIViewActions():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        list = kwargs.get('list', False)
        create = kwargs.get('create', False)
        retrieve = kwargs.get('retrieve', False)
        update = kwargs.get('update', False)
        partial_update = kwargs.get('partial_update', False)
        destroy = kwargs.get('destroy', False)

    def retrieve_actions(self):
        actions = {}

        if self.list:
            actions['get'] = 'list'

        if self.create:
            actions['post'] = 'create'

        if self.retrieve:
            actions['get'] = 'retrieve'

        if self.update:
            actions['patch'] = 'update'

        if self.partial_update:
            actions['patch'] = 'partial_update'

        if self.destroy:
            actions['delete'] = 'destroy'

        return actions

APIViewActions = APIViewActions(delete=True)
```

So, when this is called:

```
APIViewActions.retrieve_actions()
```

I receive the following error:

AttributeError: 'APIViewActions' object has no attribute 'list'

Surely, `self.list` should be `False`? I essentially want the APIViewActions() call to be loosely defined, e.g., could be called like this:

`APIViewActions = APIViewActions(delete=True)`

`APIViewActions = APIViewActions(list=true, delete=True)`

How would this be achieved?

Comment: You're missing the reference to the instance in your `__init__` lines, i.e. `self.list = kwargs.get('list', False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the `self` (name use as a convention) to refer your instance before assigning attributes.

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.list = kwargs.get('list', False) 
    self.create = kwargs.get('create', False) 
    self.retrieve = kwargs.get('retrieve', False) 
    self.update = kwargs.get('update', False) 
    self.partial_update = kwargs.get('partial_update', False) 
    self.destroy = kwargs.get('destroy', False)
```

Answer (score 4):

`self` is missing in class.

```
class APIViewActions():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.list = kwargs.get('list', False)
        self.create = kwargs.get('create', False)
        self.retrieve = kwargs.get('retrieve', False)
        self.update = kwargs.get('update', False)
        self.partial_update = kwargs.get('partial_update', False)
        self.destroy = kwargs.get('destroy', False)
```